# coding advice: dom manipulation - splitting text into dynamic spans

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

## See edited post below for updated problem

I've solved a dom manipulation problem, but I am not convinced that it is the cleanest and clearest way to solve it.

old problem: convert the innerHTML from a set of elements into three spans and replace the innerHTML of each element by the newly converted spans.

For example:

```
<h1>This is awesome<h1>
<h1>
  <span class="color-1">This</span>
  <span class="color-2">is</span>
  <span class="color-3">awesome</span>
</h1>
```

I have used a lot of slicing and joining and a recursive function, but I think I might get the same results with less code, for example making use of more es6 array helper methods. Can you help me?

### Requirements

1. InnerHTML words should be counted and divided by three
2. In case there is a residual, the last span should contain the least number of words, but never have less words than 1 compared to the first (and 2nd) span.
3. So with 15 words, each span contains 5
4. With 17 words, the first 2 spans should contain 6 words, the last one 5
5. With only 2 words, the first and second span should contain each 1 word and the last span is empty.

   ```
   const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2 , h3, h4"));
   convertElements(elements);

   function convertElements(elements) {
     const textsInsideElements = elements.map(htmlElement => htmlElement.innerHTML);
     textsInsideElements.forEach((text, index) =>
                           convertToSeparateSpans(elements, text, index));
   }

   function convertToSeparateSpans(elements, string, index) {
     const wordsPerSpan = calculateWordsPerSpan(string, 3);
     const wordParts = pushWordSpansToSeparateArrays([], string, wordsPerSpan, -1);
     const joinedTextSpans = wordsToSpanElements(wordParts);
     elements[index].innerHTML = joinedTextSpans;
   }

   function calculateWordsPerSpan(string, totalSpans) {
     const totalLength =  string.split(' ').length;
     const residual = totalLength % totalSpans;
     const firstPart = residual === 0 ? 
                         totalLength / totalSpans : Math.ceil(totalLength / totalSpans);
     const middlePart = residual === 1 ? firstPart * 2 - 1 : firstPart * 2;
     const endPart = totalLength;
     return [].concat(firstPart).concat(middlePart).concat(endPart);
   }

   function pushWordSpansToSeparateArrays(result, string, stringPartials, index) {
     const firstIteration = index === -1;
     const indexOutOfBounds = stringPartials[index + 1] === undefined;
     const stringToArr = string.split(' ');
     const firstString = stringToArr.slice(0, stringPartials[index + 1]).join(' ');
     const subsequentString = stringToArr
                                .slice(stringPartials[index], stringPartials[index + 1])
                                .join(' ');
     if(firstIteration) {
       result.push(firstString);
       pushWordSpansToSeparateArrays(result, string, stringPartials, index + 1)
       return result;
     } else if (!firstIteration && !indexOutOfBounds) {
       result.push(subsequentString);
       pushWordSpansToSeparateArrays(result, string, stringPartials, index + 1);   
     }
   }

   function wordsToSpanElements(wordParts) {
     const spanArray = wordParts.map((part, index) => 
     `<span class="color-${index+1}">${part}</span>`);
     return spanArray.join(' ');
   }
   ```

### EDIT

With some help from @Nathan Stockton, I finally formatted my code with this:

```
    function pushWordSpansToSeparateArrays(string) {
      const splitString = string.trim().split(" ");
      const hasResidual1 = splitString.length%3 === 1;
      const firstThird = Math.ceil(splitString.length/3);
      let secondThird = hasResidual1 ? firstThird * 2 - 1  : firstThird * 2;
      return []
        .concat(splitString.slice(0, firstThird).join(' '))
        .concat(splitString.slice(firstThird, secondThird).join(' '))
        .concat(splitString.slice(secondThird, splitString.length).join(' '));
    }
    const test = "This is a long string";
    console.log(pushWordSpansToSeparateArrays(test))
    // output ["This is", "a long", "string"]
```

The problem with this approach is that it is not reusable for more than 3 parts.

new problem: Is there a way to make this function general to have it split words into any number of parts based on an argument, for example pushWordSpansToSeparateArrays(string, totalParts);

Comment: Please don't post links to your code, edit the question to include the relevant parts of your code instead.

Comment: @PatrickHund sorry, I put the code in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take 2 of a response - I'm off to bed now, hope it works!

```
String.prototype.splitInto = function (parts) {
  const splitString = this.trim().split(" ");
  obResponse = {};
  obResponse.values = [];
  var chunkSize = Math.floor(splitString.length/(parts));
  var spares = splitString.length%parts;
  var start = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
    obResponse.values[i] = splitString.slice(start, start+chunkSize+(spares>i?1:0));
    start = start+chunkSize+(spares>i?1:0);
  }
  return obResponse;
}
var segments = "test a b k l m n o ".splitInto(3);
console.log(segments.values);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a lot shorter and can be adapted to serve (what I think are) your needs:

```
String.prototype.splitInto3 = function () {
  const splitString = this.trim().split(" ");
  var firstThird = Math.ceil(splitString.length/3);
  var secondThird = splitString.length-Math.floor((splitString.length-firstThird)/2);
  var obResponse = {
    firstSegment: splitString.slice(0, firstThird),
    secondSegment: splitString.slice(firstThird, secondThird),
    thirdSegment: splitString.slice(secondThird, splitString.length)
  }
  return obResponse;
}
var segments = "test a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o ".splitInto3();
console.log("First third ("+segments.firstSegment.length+"): "+segments.firstSegment);
console.log("Second third ("+segments.secondSegment.length+"): "+segments.secondSegment);
console.log("Third third ("+segments.thirdSegment.length+"): "+segments.thirdSegment);
```

or as an array

```
String.prototype.splitInto3 = function () {
  const splitString = this.trim().split(" ");
  var firstThird = Math.ceil(splitString.length/3);
  var secondThird = splitString.length-Math.floor((splitString.length-firstThird)/2);
  var obResponse = [splitString.slice(0, firstThird), splitString.slice(firstThird, secondThird), splitString.slice(secondThird, splitString.length)]
  return obResponse;
}
var segments = "test a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o ".splitInto3();
console.log("First third ("+segments[0].length+"): "+segments[0]);
console.log("Second third ("+segments[1].length+"): "+segments[1]);
console.log("Third third ("+segments[2].length+"): "+segments[2]);
```

Comment: Hi Nathan thank you. The secondThird is not always 2* firstThird.

For example, if the length is 16, I want 6 5 5. Your results gives me 6 6 4. (at least that what it seems to do)

Also I would prefer an array instead of an object, but that's a minor detail

Comment: I will adjust the secondThird based on the residual. I will accept this answer.

Comment: The result is now that I get a string with words separated by comma's

Comment: This is an array - you need to join them using `.join(" ")` - so `segments[0].join(" ")` for example

Comment: yes, I figured it out, thank you. I've edited my post, because this approach does make it static (you can only use it for 3 parts). Do you know how to make the amount of parts dynamic? Which is why I came to recursive functions in the first place.